# Can I move .exe files from a file history drive to a new computer?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, file-history

If I backup my folders for Steam and GOG using the Windows 10 file history tool, would I be able to move those files to a new computer and run the .exe files?

Comment: [https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-correctly-use-file-history-to-transfer-data-files-to-a-new-windows-10-installation/](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-correctly-use-file-history-to-transfer-data-files-to-a-new-windows-10-installation/)  ---  [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restore-filehistory-to-a-new-computer/cc86efd3-b75b-4837-85bf-f39d2193ce23](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/restore-filehistory-to-a-new-computer/cc86efd3-b75b-4837-85bf-f39d2193ce23)

Comment: Gog games may be. But Steam does not work without a fresh installation of the Steam client plus authenticating on the new PC. Not sure if Steam will recognize the games in it's data folders and also the games need to be able to run without additional installation (additional components, registry entries,...).